# jQuery (v1.5.2) offset.top not rendering correctly in IE 8

Tags: jquery

`offset.left` renders correctly but when trying to place an element below another one using `offset.top`, the element is showing up about 50px higher than the element it is supposed to be under.  I've read various articles on stackoverflow that say to use `offset.top`, but doesn't seem to be working for me...

Comment: Please post the code you believe is not functioning properly.

Comment: Discovered the issue...

I have a checkbox that "unhides" hidden spans that are on the page.  When the page displays those spans, there is "header" span that provides instructions to the user.  The offset.top is calculating based off of the **original** offset of the elements rather than using the offset that occurs when the hidden spans are revealed.

I was able to place the spans directly underneath their corresponding element by using...
    offset.top + headerHeight - heightOfOriginalElement + "px";

Comment: I would flag the above comment as the answer but stackoverflow won't allow me as a new user to answer the question until 8 hours later...

Comment: Also, I'd upgrade jQuery. `1.7.1` is out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Discovered the issue...

I have a checkbox that "unhides" hidden spans that are on the page.  When the page displays those spans, there is "header" span that provides instructions to the user.  The offset.top is calculating based off of the **original** offset of the elements rather than using the offset that occurs when the hidden spans are revealed.

I was able to place the spans directly underneath their corresponding element by using...
    offset.top + headerHeight - heightOfOriginalElement + "px";